# How to save relationship when creating an entity with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems like everything I learnt about Ruby on Rails dissapeared from my mind.

I am trying to make the simplest relationship ever, between products and categories. I defined a `has_many :categories` relationship in the `Product` model, and I created a migration where I have a table with `product_id` and `category_id`.

First, I thought passing the parameters to `Product.new` would automatically add the categories. I recall it worked like this.

Then I tried doing it manually: `@product.categories = product_params[:categories]`. `product_params` is generated by the scaffold, and it is as follows:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :categories)
end
```

However, even doing it this way, `@product.categories` seems to be `nil`.

How can I store the `product_id` and `category_id` (or categories, since it is a has many relationshop) in the relationship table? I have been looking at old codes of mine with Ruby on Rails 3 and it seems like all this was handled automatically by Rails. What am I missing?!

```
`Product` model:
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => 'products_categories'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
# product.rb
class Product < AR::Base

  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  

end

#products_controller.rb

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    
  end
                        
  def create
    @product = Product.new product_params
    @product.save
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:product, :attributes, :category_ids => [])
  end

end
```

And within view:

```html
<%= form_for @product do |f| %> 
  <%=f.select :category_ids, options_for_select(Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id] }, @product.category_ids ), {}, :multiple => true  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `@product.categories.build` gives an error: `undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass` I left it the way it was (`@categories = Category.all`) but it still does not work. The categories are not saved. I will edit my post with the `Product` model.

Comment: Yep, it returns nil, because you've added `attr_accessor :categories` which overrides the :categories association declaration. Besides that, you have to use either HABTM or has_many, through. Now you mix both of them. `join_table => 'products_categories'` stands for HABTM whereas you also define `has_many :categories, through: :category_products`

Comment: I changed it again (check the update) for `has_and_belongs_to_many` because a product can have multiple categories, and a category can belong to multiple products. Why is still not working?

Comment: I've changed slightly my answer.